# Github Repo is not showing the Language Bar as well as most used Language

Tags: github, repository, github-linguist

My github repo is not showing the language statistics [in the form of the bar under 'packages'] and the most used language. I've done some testing with the same files and it seems like Github's Linguist just starts to break after a couple of commits. I've also looked into problems that might arise with vendored code and stuff like that but it doesn't seem likely since all the files worked when I tested them individually. I just don't understand why it breaks and then doesn't work again.

Here's a link to the repo: https://github.com/arshb22/Virtual-Reality-and-Game-Design

Comment: Which language(s) are you expected to be detected for your repository? Note only languages defined in https://github.com/github/linguist/blob/master/lib/linguist/languages.yml are supported on GitHub.

Comment: C#, Objective C, HLSL and other languages. I actually had it displaying the languages when I had committed around half the files and there were more ones than I had listed. It all disappeared upon adding more files.

Comment: Could you point to an existing C# file in the repository? Note that generated files will be considered "vendored" by default by Linguist and won't show up in statistics.

Comment: Inside the Assets folder of the AnimationDemo there's a C# script called Spin Controller. Most of them are located within the assets folder for the other files because they're Unity Projects.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that your repo is filled with files that have extensions that Github doesn't recognize. If your files don't have extensions used by common programming languages, Github won't be able to label them since it doesn't know what they are.

Comment: The .cs scripts in all/some of the files indicate C#. Linguist was working when I had half my repo pushed. It stopped after some number of commits.